# How to find file in directory in c

Tags: c, file, directory

I'm trying to create a function in c which scans the given directory for files of the given format (for example :- _sort.txt) and check if the directory contains that format file or not.

if directory contain file of that format then it should return -1 else 0.
but i am stuck on how to scan the directory.can anyone help me with this.

i am fairly new to c so please bear with me.

operating system :- Linux

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Linux @DavidRanieri Sir

Comment: In this case `dirent` is what you are looking for: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/dirent.h.html

Comment: You have a short example here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/readdir.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use **strstr** to find the pattern in the filename.

don't forget to include these headers:
*#include <dirent.h>*
*#include <string.h>*

```
int find_file(const char *pattern, DIR *dr) {                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    struct dirent *de;                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    int found = -1;                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    while ( (de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {                                                                                                                                              
                     
        // DT_REG is a regular file                                                                                                                                                          
        if (de->d_type == DT_REG && strstr(de->d_name, pattern) != NULL) {                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                       
            found = 0;                                                                                                                                                                 
            break;                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return found;                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

any where that you want to use this function you should pass the **DIR** which is opened with **opendir**.

```
int main() {                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    DIR *d = opendir(".");                                                                                                                                                             
    const char *pattern = "_sort.txt";                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    if (find_file(pattern, d) == 0)                                                                                                                                                    
        printf("found it\n");                                                                                                                                                          
    else                                                                                                                                                                               
        printf("not found it\n");                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

for further information about *dirent struct*:
**man readdir**